# How to test a http calls from a second class func call from within first class (APEX class testing/salesforce testing)

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex

I have an apex class A. I'm calling the function of B class from within A.

```
class A{ 
    B bobj=new B(); 
    B.function2();

    function1(); //within class A
}
```

This function1 and function2 are http calls to 2 diff rest services.

I wrote a test class with httpcallmockouts for the both function1 and function2. So the order goes like this inside APex Test class-

```
B objB=new B(); 

HttpResponse res = CalloutB.getInfoFromExternalService(); 

A objA=new A(); 
HttpResponse res = CalloutA.getInfoFromExternalService();

//Till this point my test runs successfully for http calls mock

Test.startTest(); 

objA.function1();

//Here I get an error http callout not supported for test methods for function2 of B class. 


//If I change the order above to 

//A objA=new A(); 

//HttpResponse res = CalloutA.getInfoFromExternalService(); 

//B objB=new B(); 

//HttpResponse res = CalloutB.getInfoFromExternalService(); 

//Then I get error http callout not supported for test methods for function1 of A class. 

Test.stopTest();
```

So, how do you test the http call from within another's class function calls in the first class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are not initializing the httpMock class object,so your test class is trying to hit real web service call which is not allowed from test class. What you need to do it to initialize your mockClass object and use it instead to return data rather than hitting real web service endpoint

> In main class which does the callout declare a variable which holds
> reference to created mockClass object
>
> Add a condition in your callout class which check if its a test class which is currently running using Test.isRunningTest() .
>
> If its a test class then use your mock class to return data instead of real callout
>
> If its not a test class execution context, use real callout

```
@isTest
global class ResultHttpMock implements HttpCalloutMock {

  global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
    
    HttpResponse res;
    System.debug('request inside mock '+req);
    if(req != null) {
        
        res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody(getBody());
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        res.setStatus('OK');
          
    }
    
    return res;
}

  private static String getBody() {
    String idmJsonMockResponse = '{"ednaScoreCard":{"sc":[],"etr":[{"test":"id:0","details":"false","ts":1471432074763,"stage":"1"},{"test":"ed:37","fired":false,"details":"ed:37(false) = true","ts":1471432074763,"stage":"1"}
}
```

In your Class A and Class B, hold a reference to ResultHttpMock

```
global class HttpCalloutClass {

public static HttpCalloutMock httpMock = null;
     ......
    if(Test.istestRunning() && httpMock != null) {
        Http response = httpMock.respond(request);
    } else {
        Http response = http.send(request);
    }
 }
```

In your test class, initialize the httpMock object before calling functionA() and functionB()

```
@isTest(seeAllData=false)
public class TestHttp {

  static testMethod void testfunctionA() {
     
    Test.startTest();
    
    HttpCalloutClass.httpMock = new ResultHttpMock ();
    String result = HttpCalloutClass.functionA();
    
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. if(Test.istestRunning() && httpMock != null) . This works great.